# Qt override Title bar and menu bar?

Tags: c++, qt, menubar, titlebar

I started on a project that I've been planning and I have a quick question.

I want to have as much screen space as possible.  To do this I need to make the title bar thinner and I also want to have the menu bar hide until it is hovered over.

Is there a function that would allow be to quickly just shrink the title bar.

I'm pretty sure I need to use setMenuWidget() to create a custom menu bar, and then just add the labels, signals, and the other fun menu stuff.  Am I right, is setMenuWidget() all I need beside the function that sets all of the labels and connections?  Would I have to create a variable in the class, or could I just create a function called setUpMenuBar()?

I tried to word this as well as I could.  Sometimes my questions are a bit vague so if you clarity, just ask.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can't put into words what you're trying to do, then you probably won't be able to put it into code. Not to be overly critical, but think first, code later.

Comment: No, he explained it pretty well - he just wanted a starting point, not a criticism.

Answer (score 0):

Use [full screen mode](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#showFullScreen) to get rid of the title bar. I think that would be much more user friendly than a nonstandard looking thin title bar.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you need a member variable for your custom menu bar widget depends only on your use of it. If all you do is create the menu, then no, you don't need to keep a member variable for it. "QMainWindow takes ownership of the menuBar pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time."

```
MyMainWindow::setUpMenuBar() {
    MyCustomMenuBar * menubar = new MyCustomMenuBar;
    // add all the menus
    setMenuWidget( menubar );
}
```

You can even retrieve a pointer to menubar later:

```
MyCustomMenuBar * menubar = qobject_cast<MyCustomMenuBar *>( menuWidget() );
```

If you need this pointer more often, you can either override MyMainWindow::menuWidget() or save the pointer as a member.